# Stack Exchange's style guidelines say to use the Oxford comma, but the Teams notice in the left sidebar doesn't use it

Tags: bug, wording, sidebar, stack-overflow-for-teams

**TL;DR - add a comma after "find answers" in the left-sidebar Teams dialog.**

---

In the SOfT dialog in the left sidebar, it says this:

> **Teams +**
>
> Ask questions, find answers and collaborate at work with Stack Overflow for Teams.
>
> **[Explore Teams](https://stackoverflow.co/teams?utm_medium=referral&utm_source=superusermeta-community&utm_campaign=side-bar&utm_content=explore-teams-compact)**
>
> Looking for **your Teams?**

Per [the Stack Overflow writing guide's section on commas](https://stackoverflow.design/content/guidelines/grammar-and-mechanics/#commas):

> #### Commas
>
> **Use the Oxford comma in sentences.** Don’t use a comma to separate two distinct phrases (comma splicing). Use two sentences instead.

Considering the three items (asking, finding answers, and collaborating) appear to be a list, can a comma be added before the word "and"?

---

Unrelated, but can the <kbd>+</kbd> button link to something to make a team and *not* a definition of SOfT? Worse, [in SOfT](https://stackoverflowteams.com), there is a dialog with a bolded word "TEAMS" followed by a <kbd>+</kbd> button that actually does make a new team.

Comment: Looking at the SOfT tag wiki, I consider this affecting Q&A as it's present on public Q&A. That said, if this is still off-topic, I can delete this and file a *Cosmetic Issue* support ticket.

Comment: It seems to be a stylistic choice called the [Oxford comma](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/412/should-i-put-a-comma-before-the-last-item-in-a-list). Personally, I save a character and don't use it. The "+" button should link to something though.

Comment: Having a "plus" character clearly creates the expectation that clicking it will lead to adding something, not open info popup. That's just bad UX, which sadly happens more and more lately in SE. (It's trivial to have info icon instead of plus icon)